# Is the equality of two DFAs a decidable problem?

Tags: computability, automata, finite-automata, decision-problem

So given two DFAs, is the problem of finding if they generate the same language a Decidable problem?

I already know that Equality of two CFL is not Decidable

but what about Equality of two DFAs? considering most of the problems with DFAs are decidable, is this decidable as well ?

Comment: Yes, it is decidable in linear time  https://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~deepakd/atc-common/hopcroft-karp-71-114.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to decide whether the languages generated by two DFAs $A_1,A_2$ by the same, construct a DFA $A_\Delta$ for the symmetric difference $L(A_1) \Delta L(A_2) := (L(A_1) \setminus L(A_2)) \cup (L(A_2) \setminus L(A_1))$, and check whether $L(A_\Delta) = \emptyset$.

Here are some more details. You can construct $A_\Delta$ using the *product construction*: construct a product automaton, and use $(F_1 \times \overline{F_2}) \cup (\overline{F_1} \times F_2)$ as the set of accepting states.

In order to check whether $L(A_\Delta)$ is empty or not, it suffices to check whether some accepting state is reachable from the initial state, and this can be done using BFS/DFS.

Answer (score 4):

Given two DFA $D_1$ and $D_2$, equality of of $D_1$ and $D_2$ and checking if $D_1$ and $D_2$ generate the same language are same things.

Yes, this problem is decidable. You can [minimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) both $D_1$ and $D_2$ and compare their transition functions. Given a DFA, the [minimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) reduces the number of states to a minimum number and this DFA is unique.
 [Here is](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48136/testing-two-dfas-generate-the-same-language-by-trying-all-strings-upto-a-certain) alternative approach.

Comment: I believe you're conflating "equivalence" of the DFAs and their equality.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, I use the term "equality" as a synonym of "equivalence" because the OP uses the term "Equality".

Comment: The two are not the same, though. Even after minimization, the automata are not *equal*. We know them to be isomorphic, though, which is certainly decidable (if potentially harder than equality).