# How to find the intersection of two FAs and then check if two FAs are equal?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, equality, finite-sets, finite-model-theory

[image: Two FAs]

I am still quite confused on how to properly handle in answering the `intersection and equality of two FAs` in terms of table form and manipulating its transformation. It is a bit challenging at times when I encounter new FAs to compare. It would help a lot if there would be a proper way and tip to understand the question in a well manner and the approach to answering it properly.

My attempt last time on another question for checking two FAs (I added variables on the nodes when I complemented them):
[image: FA1]
[image: FA2]
[image: ATTEMPT]
Google sheets attempt editable link (included the complement attempt and transition table and graph):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177-OzwGzMrdK9aBB6-PkWa6Odp-2GXaM/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103963659104705170979&rtpof=true&sd=true

Your responses would indeed help me a lot on this one since I am still getting the grasp of understanding in Finite Automata intersection and equality. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/81813/755

Comment: Already read that, it would help a lot if we can focus on the question sample above I have posted. It would make it more clearer if the process involves just like my attempt. @D.W.